# grep not working correctly

Tags: linux, bash, cgi

Hi i have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-Type: text/html
echo -e "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title> Pagina Web </title>
        </head>
        <body>
"
echo -e "<h3>AUTH</h3>"

echo -e "<h1>Buscador</h1>
        <form action='auth.sh' method='POST' enctype='text/plain'>
                Buscar: <input type='text' name='busqueda'>
                <input type='submit' value='BUSCAR'>
        </form>
        <br><br><br><br>
"
read busqueda
correcte=`echo $busqueda|awk -F'=' '{printf $2}'|sed s/+/\ /g`

if [ -z "$correcte" ]; then
        cat /var/log/auth.log | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/<br>/g'
else
        #The 'grep "$correcte" is not working properly'
        cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "$correcte" | tr -d " " | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/<br>/g'
fi

echo -e "
        </body>
</html>
```

Everithing seems to work correctly, but when i execute the search, it enters correctly in the second option, but it doesn't work. I debugged, and the word that is read from the post arrives correctly under the var $correcte, but when the grep executes, there isn't any information shown. The word that i read from the form is obviously present in the file, auth.log(some word like "invalid").

When i hardcode ..."grep invalid" , it works fine but when i do as in the code it doesn't.

Anyone kowns why the grep is not working properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added an `echo ${correcte}` right after you set the correcte variable? Perhaps your awk/sed is not accomplishing what you think it is everytime.

Comment: Did you test it from the commandline? `read busqueda` will not work through a webserver.

Comment: @WalterA yes, the value that i get is the correct one but the "grep $correcte", doenst work because if i hardcode "grep invalid", it works properly